# What do you call a DLL that is placed on the same directory as the EXE?

Tags: assemblies, terminology, configuration-management

I need a little help in terminology.

You can put an assembly in the GAC to "share" these assembly globally in the machine. What do you call if you put the assembly in the same directory where the executable is?

I have been calling it "side-by-side" because the EXE and the DLL is "side-by-side". I've done [some reading](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Side-by-side_assembly) and it seems that "side-by-side" stands for something else

EDIT: Are those DLLs called "Private assemblies"?

Answer (score 0):

Side-by-side refers to two versions of the same assembly (i.e. 1.0.0.0, 1.1.0.0) being installed in the GAC at the same time.

Whether in the GAC or in the same local directory as the main application EXE assembly, this DLL assembly would be known as a dependency of the main assembly.

Comment: But what do you call this "configuration" mode where the DLL (dependency assembly) is being placed on the same directory as the EXE (main assembly)?

Comment: It's sometimes referred to as Xcopy deployment, as you deploy the assemblies by copying them to a file location.

Comment: Yes, the deployment can be called "Xcopy" deployment, but what do you call the assembly? Suggestions are "local" assemblies and "private" assemblies. Is there an official term for this?

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is using the terms local versions (NOT GAC) and system versions (GAC)

Comment: Is this the official term for these assemblies?

Comment: They are picked up from a msdn article. You can se the terms used here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375142(v=vs.85).aspx